KVM virtual machines interfaces not communicating over private networks
Setup is very simple.
For both virtual machines:

First network connection is on the "labnet" doing dhcp and it works
fine.
The second network connection is on "network1"


Each interface on the VMs sends LLDP - but they don't receive each others' LLDP.
tcpdump shows outbound only.
